# Best way to handle Categories Partial View in ASP.NET MVC 3 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a list of blog post categories(~20) in a look up table.
I want to display them on multiple pages as list of hyperlinks that user can click.
I also want to display them in a dropdown list in 2 or more places(different view pages)

The follow works & I see categories as a menu/list of hyperlinks.
But this will cause me modify multiple controller where I need to show the categories.
What is the best practice to handle this so that I have minimal code change?

```
//#1 I added new class in one of my model:
namespace MyApp.Models
{
   ...
   public class ShowPostModel
   {
      public Post Post { get; set; }
      public IEnumerable<Category> Categories { get; set; }
   }
   public class Category
   {
      public string _id { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }      
   }
}

//#2 Populating the controller
namespace MyApp.Controllers
{
  public class BlogController : Controller
  {
    public ActionResult ShowPost()
    {
        ShowPostModel viewModel = new ShowPostModel();
        viewModel.Post = ReadBlogPostFromDB();
        viewModel.Categories = ReadCategoriesFromDB();
        return View(viewModel);
    }
  }
}

//#3 This is from my main view for showing the Post:
@Html.Partial("_Categories", Model.Categories)

//#4 This is my _Categories partial view:
@model IEnumerable<MyApp.Models.Category>
<section>
   <header><b>Categories</b></header>
   <ul style="padding:0;margin:0;">
      @foreach (var cat in Model)
      {
        <li>
           <a href="/post/browse/cid=@cat._id">@cat.Name</a>
        </li>
      }
   </ul>
 </section>
```

Thanks for reading

**Edit:
I made these changes and it seems working as well. 
Any comments or improvements I can make here?**

//#1 deleted this line from public class ShowPostModel (model is now DRY)

`public IEnumerable<Category> Categories { get; set; }`//deleted

//#2 created a base controller and inherit from it

```
public abstract class BlogBaseController : Controller
   {
      public BlogBaseController()
      {
         ViewBag.Categories = ReadCategoriesFromDB();                  
      }
   }
```

//#3 force all controller where I need categories to inherit from base controller

```
public class BlogController : BlogBaseController
```

//#4 change how I read in my views

```
@Html.Partial("_Categories", (IEnumerable<MyApp.Models.Category>)@ViewBag.Categories)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the categories in enough places, you can encapsulate this into a base controller class, and override OnActionExecuted.

I would then put the Categories into a property on the ViewBag and pass it into your partial view from there, and leave your view's model alone.

Comment: Also, in your controllers, you can use a ViewData object to store other relevant data e.g a list of categories and that you can refer to in a view/partial- but @Michael has covered it well.

Comment: @leonxki: That would still require me to change each controller where I need the categories available.

Answer (score 1):

i wonder why no one has suggested using RenderAction. you can write this Action method in you base controller. this will make it available in all derived controller. this way you can have your categories view strongly typed. Moreover, you should put your Categeories view in Views/Shared directory so every controller has access to this view. Doing so will keep you DRY and you still have the benefits of having strongly typed view. 
**EDIT** By the way you don't have to have base controller to use renderaction. Although above approach is valid and i prefer doing like this but you can also have a nvaigation controller like

```
Public NavigationController:Controller()
{
     public ActionResult Categories()
    {
        var Categories = FetchFromDB();
        return View(Categoires);
    }
}
```

Now you can call this action method using renderAction on anywhere in your application

Comment: Not sure if I followed your approach. Thanks

Comment: @zahid he would probably want it returned as a PartialView, so it can be rendered inside a Post view.

Comment: @frennky when you have Categories action and corresponding view in shared for instance you can call it as renderpartial provided that you have model data available on the calling view as in example of Posts

Comment: @Projapati what exactly u did not follow

Comment: +1 Yep, i agree with this - and have done the exact same thing. My colleague on the other hand prefers having the duplicated code in each controller. It's a matter of preference. And yes this should probably return a partial view, and have `[ChildActionOnly]` attribute.

Comment: @RPM exactly it is meant to be a childAction only and should not be allowed to be called directly from browser

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try creating 2 display for templates, one to display in link and one to display in dropdown.  Depending on the page you tell the view to use the specific template.

Comment: That is fine. But my main concern is where to put the code for categories? Modifying each controllers seem bad and not DRY

Comment: By Modifying each controller, do you mean doing this   viewModel.Post = ReadBlogPostFromDB();
        viewModel.Categories = ReadCategoriesFromDB(); in every controller?  If yes, why don't you call that function from within the Model so you don't have to do it from the controller?

Comment: I had modification in the controller and the model in my code. In my model I had to add Category class and IEnumerable<Category> in another model class. Then in controller I had to populate the List<Category>() so that view can read it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Filter that populates your categories and adds it to ViewData/ViewBag. You can then apply this filter to the controllers/actions that require the categories.

For displaying, you can use EditorTemplates or Partials to keep your UI code DRY...

HTH.